# Decomposing a circle into similar pieces

Tags: geometry, general-topology, puzzle, recreational-mathematics, tiling

Is it possible to decompose a circle into finitely many similar disjoint pieces, one of which contains the circle's center in its interior?

Comment: I mean "disjoint pieces that also have the same shape". But not necessarily the same size or rotation. I suspect its not possible but I'd like a proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A version of this question was asked on MO a while back: "[Is it possible to dissect a disk into congruent pieces, so that a neighborhood of the origin is contained within a single piece?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17313/is-it-possible-to-dissect-a-disk-into-congruent-pieces-so-that-a-neighborhood-of)."  It was determined that that particular problem (which I now think is identical to yours as currently posted)
is open, and appears in *Unsolved Problems in Geometry*.

There Anton Geraschenko posted this interesting dissection:

          
[image]

which answers another version (perhaps the first version?) of your question.
In the comments another dissection was given by 'sobe86':

          
[image]