# Slice of pizza with no crust

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, puzzle

The following question came up at a conference and a solution took a while to find.

> **Puzzle.** Find a way of cutting a pizza into finitely many congruent pieces such that at least one piece of pizza has no crust on it.

We can make this more concrete,

> Let $D$ be the unit disc in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Find a finite set of subsets of $D$, $\mathcal{A}=\{A_i\subset D\}_{i=0}^n$, such that
>
> - for each $i$, $A_i$ is simply connected and equal to the closure of its interior
> - for each $i, j$ with $i\neq j$, $\operatorname{int}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{int}(A_j)=\emptyset$
> - $\bigcup\mathcal{A}=D$
> - for each $i,j$, $A_i=t(A_j)$ where $t$ is a (possibly orientation reversing) rigid transformation of the plane
> - for some $i$, $\lambda(A_i\cap\partial D)=0$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on the boundary circle.

Note that we require only that $\lambda(A_i\cap\partial D)=0$ and not that $A_i\cap\partial D=\emptyset$. I know of a solution but am interested in what kinds of solutions other people can find, and so I welcome the attempt.

Comment: Don't you want $\lambda(\partial A_i\cap\partial D)=0$ where $\lambda$ is the measure on the boundary of the circle (you should have all the dimensions the same else the lower dimensional piece has zero measure anyway)?

Comment: @MarkBennet: I think Daniel is considering the unit circle to be the boundary of the unit disk.

Comment: Well $A_i\cap\partial D$ is a subset of the boundary circle.

Comment: @DanielRust I was reading the measure as the measure on the disk. I agree it is OK as is.

Comment: Related on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17313/is-it-possible-to-dissect-a-disk-into-congruent-pieces-so-that-a-neighborhood-o/17451#17451

Comment: I'd imagine the solution involves some multiple of pie.

Comment: D-D-D-DUCPLICATE !!!!11      http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71959/decomposing-a-circle-into-similar-pieces/71977

Comment: @AbdulhKhazzakGustavElFakiri The question is different and identical to the MO link Daniel R mentioned above.

Comment: So the whole circle is pizza, and the crust is the outside line, of width zero?

Comment: I wonder how the mathematical formulation is "more concrete" than the physical description of the problem!

Comment: In the mathematical formulation, you don't say anywhere that the subsets $A_i$ should be pairwise disjoint (or even almost pairwise disjoint).  That would seem to be essential; otherwise the problem might be trivial.

Comment: @AriBrodsky You're entirely correct! I'll add that condition.

Comment: But is there a way to use a pizza cutter (or other kitchen utensils) to cut a pizza into one of these arrangements? I would enjoy seeing a photo of a real pizza cut this way...

Comment: For the record, only @WarrenP has asked if the pizza is circular, everyone else has assumed the condition. And everyone knows pies are square.

Comment: @Anthony: pies are round, cornbread are square...

Comment: Every answer thus far involves the pieces touching the crust ( 1 point ). Is there an answer that doesn't require touching the crust?

Comment: What if the restaurant had only lasagnas?

Comment: A [recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03794) seems to suggest there are an uncountable set of solutions to this problem. **neat!!**

Comment: @robjohn I ask this to you because you are awesome :) What is "int"? And why do we need to have int$A_i \cap$ int$A_j = \emptyset$?

Comment: @robjohn  P.s. Merry Christmas!!

Comment: @Turing: $\operatorname{int}(A_i)\cap \operatorname{int}(A_j)=\emptyset$ means that the interiors of the $A_i$ are disjoint. Merry Christmas!

Comment: This is the most complex description I have ever seen.

Comment: Not to necro a question, but couldn't you just cut off the crust on the entire pizza and then slice the pizza as usual to get 12 crustless pieces? Or if there are people who want crust, then cut the crust off, but just not for the entire pizza. Had it been said/implied you can't cut the crust off?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang that does not satisfy the "all slices must be congruent" assumption. You can't just throw pieces away.

Answer (score 151):

Here is another with 12 pieces, but all pieces have the same orientation:

$\hspace{32mm}$[image]

Using this idea, the pizza can be divided into $6n$ equal pieces with the same orientation for any $n$. However, to have some pieces with no crust, we need $n\gt1$. Above is $n=2$, here is $n=3$:

$\hspace{32mm}$[image]

To cut a pizza like this, a blade shaped like, and as long as one sixth of, the circumference of the pizza would be most useful, since all of the cuts are this size and shape.

---

Here is Mathematica code that will generate these sliced pizzas for any $n$:

```
Pizza[n_] := 
 Module[{g, arcs = {Thickness[1.3/400], Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}}, 
  For[i = 0, i < 6, For[j = 0, j < n, AppendTo[arcs,
     Rotate[Rotate[Circle[{-1, 0}, 1, {0, Pi/3}],
       j Pi/3/n, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}], i Pi/3, {0, 0}]]; ++j]; ++i]; 
  Show[Graphics[arcs], ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotRange -> 1.01 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

---

**Motivation**

I thought of the construction of a regular hexagon: you draw a circle with a compass, and then mark arcs on the circle whose chords are the radius of the circle. Due to the properties of equilateral triangles, each arc is exactly $1/6$ of the circumference of the circle, and the chords of those arcs form a regular hexagon. At each vertex of the hexagon, the compass will span to the next vertex (by construction) and to the center of the circle (again, by construction).

Connecting each vertex to the center with arcs centered at the previous vertex, we get the circle tiled by $6$ curvy triangles with congruent sides; two convex sides and one concave side. The centers of the convex sides are the opposite vertices of the curvy triangle. Since the chords of the curved sides have a length $1$ radius, we can trace out the interior convex sides with a congruent arc rotating about the opposite vertex.

$\hspace{32mm}$[image]

Since we can sweep out these $6$ triangles with these congruent arcs, we can split up the curvy triangles into any number of congruent pieces with these arcs.

Comment: Is it hard to find a general form for all possible solutions?

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: it's likely to be harder to prove that you have all possible solutions than to find what turn out to be all possible solutions.  Are there solutions other than mine and robjohn's (and their reflections and rotations?).

Comment: Curious, what made you think of this solution?

Comment: @hadsed: I have added a section on the motivation.

Comment: It moves! It moves!

Comment: This answer just gets better and better. well worth the 56 upvotes and counting.

Comment: @robjohn I used one of your brilliant images in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890706/what-is-the-oldest-open-problem-in-geometry/895525#895525) but I'm mindful that you might not approve me using it. If you would like me to remove the image I'm more than happy to respect that.

Comment: @DanielRust: No problem.

Comment: What kind of software did you use to make a moving image like that? +1 anyway

Comment: @Venus: I used Mathematica to make the animation.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 109):

Here is one solution in $12$ pieces.

[image]

Comment: This is the solution I had in mind as well. There are also (a family of) solutions where all pieces have the same orientation.

Comment: +1: I was working on a drawing of this. Back to the drawing board :-)

Comment: @DanielRust One begins by putting a circular arc of equal curvature to the circle from the six obvious points on the boundary to the six interior points at which a straight line meets an arc (delete the straight lines. Then the congruent pieces can be subdivided?

Comment: Similar to the drawing here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/17451/12357

Comment: Six of the pieces here only have crust on one corner, but didn't the problem say absolutely none?

Comment: @Trejkaz: The requirement is only that the measure of crust included in some piece $A_i$, i.e. $\lambda(A_i \cap \partial D)$, be 0. A single point of idealized zero-thickness crust is OK since that has measure 0.

Comment: Here's an SVG of this solution with each slice a different color to show how not only how this works but how neat it is to have zorro at your birthday party. http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/8dHYP/1/

Comment: Hmmm, yummy Escher-type pizza...

Comment: Someone has to ask this: What if we really require $A_i\cap \partial D = \emptyset$ for at least one $i$, that is at least one piece, including its boundary, must lie entirely in the interior of the disk?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: that appears to be an open problem

Comment: @mike4ty4 It's fair enough to have ideals, but someone who is thinking more about the pizza than the semantics will probably consider a 0-width crust to be less than ideal. Illustrating the danger of stating mathematical problems in real-world terms which people might relate with. :D

Comment: True. But isn't it easy to accomodate a nonzero-width crust simply by modifying the construction so the straight lines terminate higher up the curved ones, so as to not include any crust?

Comment: @mike4ty4: I don't see how you could do that and keep the pieces all congruent.

Comment: @Robert Israel: What about this: http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2949/lj0s.png ? (The dotted circle is the inner border of the thick crust) Looks pretty congruent to me, at least as best as I could draw.

Comment: @mike4ty4: Do you think a region with four corners can be congruent to a region with three corners?

Comment: Umm... Oh! Now I see... I didn't read it carefully enough -- we need EVERY region congruent to EVERY other. Never mind!

Comment: So I wonder: can you do it with thick crust? :)

Comment: @RobertIsrael I used one of your brilliant images in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890706/what-is-the-oldest-open-problem-in-geometry/895525#895525) but I'm mindful that you might not approve me using it. If you would like me to remove the image I'm more than happy to respect that.

Answer (score -8):

If this violates the parameters in a clear way, consider this a teaching opportunity.  Would this count:

[image]

Comment: How are these pieces "congruent"?

Comment: This does violate the conditions, as we need all pieces to be congruent.  That is, every piece must be identical (shape, size, etc.) except for orientation.  Good try though--it was what popped in my head first before I noticed the "congruent" requirement.

Comment: So the center violates it then? Would that mean at least one slice needs to meet the crust?

Comment: unfortunately the boundary of each slice has a different curvature (which violates the congruency condition).

Comment: What if I split it in quarters with two more slices, then it would just be the middle 4 that were off, right?

Comment: @Anthony - Congruent means that you can overlay the shapes one on top of the other. rings of different sizes do not have this property.

Comment: Anthony, you're confusing congruence with similarity.