# Shapes for tiling a circular disk?

Tags: geometry, tiling, tessellations

Does anyone know of a catalog of sorts for what shapes are allowed for tiling a circular disk?  For example, if you are allowed one piece to tile the disk, are all the possibilities essentially "pie"-shaped wedges, like these examples below?
[image: "pie" shaped wedges]
...where all the pieces meet at a common point at the center of the circle, and all the pieces have an edge which makes up the circumference of the disk?  Are all one-piece tilings rotationally symmetric?  Or are there other possibilities of exactly covering the disk with a single tile?  What about for two or more different tiles? Is there a better set of terms I should use in my search?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481527/slice-of-pizza-with-no-crust) (and especially the answers) might interest you. I think you'll find there are many open problems in this direction.

Comment: A slightly related MathOverflow thread: [Is it possible to dissect a disk into congruent pieces, so that a neighborhood of the origin is contained within a single piece?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/17313/1916)

Comment: Yes, those are definitely interesting, and certainly answer the question about whether each tile has to have an edge on the circumference.

Answer (score 1):

I found one example of a tessellation that doesn't use sectors.
https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~breakingaway/Lessons/TOAC/TOAC.htm

Not sure if there are others, but that might give you ideas.