# Is there a known name for curved circular sector(s)?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology, circles

Wiki provides the names of some types of
[Circular triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_triangle),
like
[Reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle),
[Arbelos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbelos),
[a triquetra figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra).

Consider this special kind of circular triangles:
they partition a unit circle into $n$ congruent parts by $n$ arcs,
each arc is a $1/6$-th of the unit circle:

[image]

Question: Is there a known name for this kind of circular triangle(s)?

Perhaps, something like "curved circular sector"
or "arched circular sector"?

Comment: +1 for the question...but is it the question for the Asymptote? :-)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but this reminds me of [finding a slice of pizza with no crust](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481527/slice-of-pizza-with-no-crust/481702#481702).

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks. Asymptote is just a tool, and you are right, if was used for the figure.